# Access photos uploaded from mobile facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot access photos uploaded from facebook mobile application, i have "user_photos" permission, when i call album api it gets me the Mobile upload album but when i try to access photos of this album it returns empty, same problem is with Instagram photos, any help ?

**Album call**

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + {UID} + "/albums?fields=cover_photo,count,name&access_token=" + {Access_token};
```

**Album photos**

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + {albumId} + "/photos?fields=picture,source&limit=" + pageSize + "&offset=" + offset + "&access_token=" + {Access_token};
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find the solution?