# images uploaded from facebook mobile not appearing in javascript api call

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, photos

I need help understanding why I am unable to access images uploaded using the Facebook mobile application. The use case is that an end user opens the Facebook application from their mobile device and selects Photos=>Camera Roll. Then, they may select a single photo or a group of photos. Finally, they Post the photo(s). Via the Javascript SDK I am unable to access these photos using the request below.

Here is my request:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/' + albumID + '?fields=photos.limit(200).fields(images,height,width,picture,id)',...
```

This request returns all images within an album with the exception of images uploaded through the Facebook mobile as outlined above.

If the user shares the exact same image(s) directly from their camera roll (i.e. Gallery) via Image=> Share => Facebook => Post I have no problem accessing the image(s).

I do not see an additional field through the Graph API Explorer that suggests another request or field must be added in order to access these photos. I do not see additional permissions that might be required to access these photos. Currently, I am asking for these permissions:

```
scope="user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags"
```

Is this a known Facebook issue or user error (my fault)? Do I need additional permissions or fields in my request to access these images? Am I way off, not making the correct request to get these images uploaded through the Facebook Mobile API?

I have found one other question on SO that identifies the same issue but it did not offer any insight to resolve the issue - [Access photos uploaded from mobile facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475127/access-photos-uploaded-from-mobile-facebook-graph-api)